# Convert char array to String

Tags: casting, arduino

How can I convert a char array to String with Arduino?

```
char charArray[];
String string = String(charArray); // This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5):

A String type is initialized similarly to a C constructor:

```
String randomString(charArray);
```

There are various overloads of the String constructor including char collections.

**Doc:**

- http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/string